# Why JPQL returns only first and last field in query result using AS?

Tags: eclipselink, jpa-2.0, jpql

I have a model:

```
public class SomeModel extends Model {

      private String name;

      private String description;

      private String comment;

      ... a lot of other fields

      private String note;

}
```

I want to get the list of models from database as list of maps with only needed fields. I'm doing it following way:

```
EntityManager em = GuiceConfigSingleton.inject(EntityManager.class); 

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT 
o.name AS ModelName, 
o.description AS ModelDescription, 
o.comment AS ModelComment,
o.note AS ModelNote 
FROM SomeModel o");

query.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_TYPE, ResultType.Map);
```

Resultlist of this query is a list of maps. And every map contains only first(ModelName) and last(ModelNote) field (other fields is not empty in database). When I'm doing it without "as" using just:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT 
o.name, 
o.description, 
o.comment,
o.note 
FROM SomeModel o");
```

I got all fields but without proper keys. What's wrong?

Screenshots with simplified example:

With "AS": http://imgur.com/bKZnqSx
Without "AS": https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2G3T.jpg

**UPDATE:**
It was a bug in EclipseLink 2.5.0. With 2.5.2 everything is ok!

Comment: Please consider rewording your question, it doesn't make much sense as it stands now. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Thanks Rick! I've just edited my questioon. Hope it looks better now.

Comment: "without proper keys"? What do you mean?

Comment: If I use first query and cast result to list of map. Every map looks like this: {"ModelName": somename, "ModelNote": note}. But in second case (without "as") I just get the model field names ("name", "note" etc.) but I want to customize it. Of course, I know how to do it, but the question is: Why I get only first and last field when I use "as"?

Comment: Try not putting your remapped names in quotes. `"select name as ModelName, description as ModelDescription ..."`

Comment: Thank you dcsohl! I've already tried it. The main problem that I get only 2 fields in map instead of 4. I get only the first and the last. All other fields are just bypassing. If I change the order I still get the very first and the last so it doesn't depend on what field it exactly is.

Comment: Yes, I understand your problem. But looking around, I don't see `AS foobar` in quotes elsewhere in sample JPQL queries, so I thought it worth a try. The other thing I see pretty universally in JPQL queries is qualifying the variable names. `SELECT o.name AS ModelName, o.description AS ModelDescription, o.comment AS ModelComment, o.note AS ModelNote FROM SomeModel o`

Comment: Sorry, dcsohl! You're absolutely right! At first I use example with constants like "select 1 as first, 2 as second, 3 as third..." but Rick told me it was nonsense and I've edited it and type that wrong JPQL. Question is still open, but thank you anyway!

Comment: @sasha: How your `Model` class look like (i.e. are you using JPA inheritance, etc.)? What are the remaining fields in 'SomeModel' class (Strings, others...)? Are you sure you are reading rows from the query resultList correctly?

Comment: @wypieprz: Actually this example was pretty much simplified. My models extend org.eclipse.persistence.internal.dynamic.DynamicEntityImpl This strange behavior doesn't depend on other fields (it can be Long, Date whatever). This strange behavior remains even with constants like "select 1 as one, 2 as two, 3 as three from Model o". Even this query returns me only first (one) and last (three) in maps. About reading the result: because I set hint to query I just cast the result to List<Map<String,Object>>. And this works well if I don't use "as" in query.

Comment: @wypieprz: I've added some screenshots, please, take a look if you have a time!

Comment: @sasha: Just one more question - are you using EclipseLink's dynamic entities rather than plain JPA ones? I was trying to reproduce the problem using your `SomeModel` class as a plain JPA entity but in this case the results are retrieved properly either with or without "AS" keyword.

Comment: @wypieprz just create a sample with plain JPA entities and get the same result. BUT when I switch from EclipseLink 2.5.0 to 2.5.2 the problem is gone! It was a bug in old version. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @wypieprz Can you please tell me how to close this question? Or I can just delete it?

Comment: @sasha: good to hear that! Don't delete the question as it contain useful information for others. You can submit the answer and accept it according to [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com). BTW. it also seem to work with my 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in 2.5.0 version of EclipseLink. Since 2.5.1 everything is ok!

Lesson learned: **always check for the last release**.

Answer (score 0):

there is an other way to fetch these fields

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("your existing query");

    final List<Object[]> rsList = (List<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
    for (Object[] objects : rsList) {

        String modelName = objects[0] == null ? ""
                : objects[0].toString();
        String modelDesc = objects[1] == null ? ""
                : objects[1].toString();
        String comment = objects[2] == null ? ""
                : objects[2].toString();

        String note = objects[3] == null ? ""
                : objects[3].toString();
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I already get my results I just wonder why EclipseLink has this strange behavior when I'm using "as" operator in query.